# Is valid argument always true?

Tags: arguments, logic, discrete-mathematics

In discrete mathematics,some people say,if an argument is vaild,then all the premises and the conclusion is true(in reality).But others say that an argument may be valid,but it does not mean all the premises and the conclusion to be true in reality.Whose thinking is right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

> If "*the earth exploded today,*" then "*every human would be dead*".

Valid argument, but neither the hypothesis nor conclusion are true (in reality...).

Comment: Is it valid, though? There are humans in space. You could say the explosion would kill them, but this probably requires additional premises about _how_ Earth explodes.

Answer (score 1):

People's terminology can vary. But in my academic community ...

An argument is "valid" if it is impossible for the premises to be true without the conclusion being true. That definition makes no claims at all about the truth of the premises or conclusion.

An argument is "sound" if it is valid and all the statements (premises and conclusion) are in true ("in reality" as the OP says).